# Calling constructor with :: operator fails

Tags: c++

I am implementing a class using singleton for logging purposes.

```
Log *Log::getInstance(){

    if(!Log::log) Log::log = new Log::Log();
    
    return Log::log;
}
```

Here, `Log::log` is a pointer to an object of Log class. This snnipet of code generates the error "expected type-specifier" on new **Log**::Log(), but if I ommit the scope resolution operator, it works fine. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Log` is the class type.

`Log::Log` is a syntax construct that in certain contexts refers to `Log`'s constructor. However it doesn't generally name it as in the names of other functions (e.g. for the purpose of address-taking).

`new` expects a type name. That is simply the syntax. `Log(...)` in a *new-expression* like `new Log(...)` will call the constructor according to the arguments `...` implicitly to construct the new object, even though `Log` is its type name, not referring to its constructor. This is consistent with the syntax for non-class types, such as `new int(1)`.

Therefore, remove `::Log` from `Log::Log`.

---

Constructors are never called explicitly in C++. You only have syntax of the form `type(...)` or `type{...}` which implicitly call constructors for class types to construct new objects. The only case where it might make sense to informally talk about "calling" a constructor might be deferred construction, in which one constructor "calls" another constructor in its *member-initializer-list*.

---

I should add that you should not implement a singleton this way. You have no way of destroying the object you created in the `new` expression automatically at program end and the initialization is not thread-safe. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern?noredirect=1&lq=1) and others for C++ singleton designs.

Comment: So I only have to call the constructor if I'm passing arguments to it?

Comment: @CíceroAugusto You never call a constructor explicitly in C++ (except in the member-initializer-list of another constructor for deferred construction).

Comment: The current standard says that the constructor does not get a name (not even the name of the class) and that being called as Log::Log is just syntax. You can also not take the address of the constructor.

Comment: @Sebastian I have updated the answer to reflect that.